# Normalized LMS Filtering in Matlab Function in Simulink

Tags: matlab, filter, simulink, least-squares, noise-reduction

I am trying to implement the normalized least mean square filter in Matlab Function in Simulink as shown below:
[image]

The code inside the Matlab Function is as follows:

```
function b = lms_update(ref,cor,adapt,N,mu)
% ref = reference signal, noise signal itself, for filter to produce
% cor = corrupted signal, total signal, to be filtered

% initialization
persistent x w

if isempty(x),x=zeros(N,1);end   % input buffer
if isempty(w),w=zeros(N,1);end % filter weights

epsil = 2.2204460492503131e-016; % epsilon for divided-by-zero

% read new input sample
x(1:N-1,1) = x(2:N,1);
x(N,1)     = cor;

if adapt
    % compute filter output
    xf = flip(x); % flip x
    
    y = w'*xf;

    e = ref - y;

    % update filter weights
    w = w + mu*e*xf/(xf'*xf + epsil);
end

b = w';
```

"desired or ref" is a sinusoidal input at a given frequency and "input or cor" is the difference between the "desired" and the output from the Simulink LMS Filter.

Then, the result is shown below:
[image]

It sort of works in that it tries to filter, but with a constant phase.

What I want my Matlab Function to do is the following:
[image]

The result is:
[image]

My code basically follows the Help for the LMS Update block.  Only thing I do differently is that I flip the x persistent variable as all the offline Matlab codes available on the web does so while the Help does not mention it.

I am using the number of coefficients to be 20 and running the sim at 0.001sec.  I would share the model, but I don't see an attachment button.  If someone teaches me how, I will.

Help, please, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
persistent x_buf w_buf

if isempty(x_buf),x_buf=zeros(1,L);end   % input buffer
if isempty(w_buf),w_buf=zeros(1,L);end % filter weights

x_buf(2:L) = x_buf(1:L-1);
x_buf(1)   = ref;

y = w_buf*x_buf';
e = ref - y;

engyPlusEps = sum(x_buf .* x_buf) + eps(ref);

for idx = 1:L
    w_tmp      = alpha * w_buf(idx);
    w_adj      = e * (x_buf(idx)/engyPlusEps) * mu;
    w_buf(idx) = w_tmp + w_adj;
end

w = w_buf;
```

LMS Update Simulink block has the source code in it (duh)